# Where is the ExecuteStoreCommand method in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 in VS2012, and I trying to delete all data of some table using `ExecuteStoreCommand`, 
something like this:

```
ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [" + tableName + "]");
```

but the problem is EF is telling me, method ExecuteStoreCommand not found. I can't understand why?

Can you tell me why?, or give me a performant solution remove all data of the table.

Comment: Are you sure? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx

Comment: @tomfanning, that depends if he is using ObjectContext or DbContext

Comment: Correct. EF5/6 are DbContext (POCO) by default unless you cast them.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
```

Comment: This answer should be mark as answer...this is a perfect solution.1 vote up for you @Justin Harvey

Comment: i am using : 
 ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT profile ON")
 But its not working... Unable to insert custom primary key. How to do that ?