# Delete all entities in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I want to delete content (only data, but not the structure and foreign keys.) of all tables (all entities using Entity Framework 4+). How can this be done?
I am using SQLCE and Entity framework with Visual Studio 2010.

```
entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM TABLENAME");
```

Above query doesn't delete all rows. Later, I would also be using a where claused like

```
entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE COL1=0");
```

Comment: by "not... foreign keys" you mean the relationships, right?

Comment: I believe that's what he means

Comment: @Juventus18 Yes I don't want to delete relationships.

Comment: Context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("DELETE FROM TABLENAME")  , will that help

Comment: duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089403/delete-all-entities-in-entity-framework

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/156813/861716

Comment: Linked questions are for SQL Server. My question is about SQL Compact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EntityFramework.Extended library to perform bulk deletes. Here's a sample of what it looks like:

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

since you want to delete everything, you could use it like this:

```
//delete all users
context.Users.Delete(u => u.UserId >= 0);
```

you can download the package from nuget, or their Github: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

It occurred to me that you may be having problems with delete because you need to enable cascade on delete. If you are using the code-first method of EF, you can do it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.UserDetail)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // <-- add this to the code-first model builder.
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a link for download from Nuget?

Comment: it is a little more complicated than that. Nuget is a package management solution for .NET. you dont really download the file, at least not directly. instead, you install the package into your project. here's a brief overview of how you can use the PackageManager Console: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: Will it work with SQL compact? Please excuse my ignorance. I am new to sqlce.

Comment: as far as i know, yes

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use `TRUNCATE TABLENAME` but if you have foreign keys, you will have to set the key count to 0, then truncate, then set keycount to 1 again:

```
"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"
"TRUNCATE TABLE TALBENAME;"
"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"
```

OR

```
"ALTER TABLE TABLENAME;"
"DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Name;"
```

Comment: please elaborate on how to set key count to 0.

Comment: SqlCeException occurred. Set option= KEYCOUNT

Comment: Sorry didn't have the syntax right. Edited again, now it should work.

Comment: invalid SET OPTION foreign_key_checks

Comment: I believe there are also ways to manage your foreign keys in Your toolbox/workbench, whichever it might be called

Comment: can you guide me through it? I am new to sqlce. BTW can it be done temporarily using toolbox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49702/discussion-between-ben-and-user2951819)

Comment: there are 3 foreign keys. Can I drop and add them again in a single query, ie. without using their names?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't see why not. `DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Name1, FK_Name2, FK_Name3;` could possibly do it.

Comment: Hardcoding the names would be the last option.