# Clear Tables in DB for unit Tests

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EFCore and xUnit for my unit tests. I've set up a DB with mock data. However, I want to check in a test if an insert in an empty DB also passes. For that I need to delete/truncate the db in a Test. I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089403/delete-all-entities-in-entity-framework/13144623#13144623) with following code:

```cs
var tableNames = context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%Migration%'").ToList();
foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
{
    await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(string.Format("DELETE FROM {0};", tableName));
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Yet I'm getting following error: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ... The statement has been terminated.`

I've tried finding some SQL statements that would allow this deletion and remove any constraint restrictions, but without any luck.

##### TL;DR

How does one delete/truncate an DB over EF-Core, ignoring all kinds of constraints.

Edit:
I thought about calling a "setup" function in all tests except this one, but I'd rather call a "truncate" function once.

Comment: Not sure how you would do that manually i.e. restore the DB to the initial state, but for this I use Respawn: https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn

Comment: Nitpicking: Once you test both Db and Code, it isn't a unit test anymore, it's an integration test.

Comment: @ZoharPeled >:( *angry programmer noises*

Comment: If you have no circular constraints, you could put a loop around your loop until the tableNames list is empty

Comment: You can use [Sqlite InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)